# WPF C# Path: How to get from a string with Path Data to Geometry in Code (not in XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, path

I want to generate a WPF Path object in Code.

In XAML I can do this:

```
 <Path Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280">
```

How can I do the same in Code?

```
 Path path = new Path();
 Path.Data = "foo"; //This won't accept a string as path data.
```

Is there a class/Method available that converts the string with PathData to PathGeometry or similar?

Surely somehow the XAML gets parsed and the Data-string converted?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
var path = new Path();
path.Data = Geometry.Parse("M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280");
```

Path.Data is of type Geometry.  Using <strike>Reflector</strike> JustDecompile *(eff Red Gate)*, I looked at the definition of Geometry for its TypeConverterAttribute (which the xaml serializer uses to convert values of type `string` to `Geometry`).  This pointed me to the GeometryConverter.  Checking out the implementation, I saw that it uses `Geometry.Parse` to convert the string value of the path to a Geometry instance.

Comment: Well, I took a minute to do a google search for the answer and didn't find anything reasonable.  So, in cases like this (simple solutions must exist), I peeked at the code.  Knowing how WPF moves from strings to complex types, I followed the lead.  Understanding the process is of second importance to knowing the answer.

Comment: @Peterdk: Is there an alternative in WP7?  How does a WP7 Path convert string to Geometry?

Comment: @Will See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596506/windows-phone-7-how-to-parse-bezier-path-string-like-in-xaml

Comment: @Nasenbaer: That's unfortunate.  If you follow the same steps I did in order to determine how it is done on desktop WPF apps, you can find the answer for store apps.

Answer (score 20):

You could use the binding mechanism.

```
var b = new Binding
{
   Source = "M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280"
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(path, Path.DataProperty, b);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Turns out you have to do this for Windows Store and Phone apps. `Geometry.Parse` is in a namespace not supported in that profile.

Answer (score 4):

To make geometry from original text string You could use  System.Windows.Media.FormattedText class with BuildGeometry() Method

```
 public  string Text2Path()
    {
        FormattedText formattedText = new System.Windows.Media.FormattedText("Any text you like",
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
              FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
               new Typeface(
                    new FontFamily(),
                    FontStyles.Italic,
                    FontWeights.Bold,
                    FontStretches.Normal),
                    16, Brushes.Black);

        Geometry geometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));

        System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
        path.Data = geometry;

        string geometryAsString = geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().ToString().Replace(",",".").Replace(";",",");
        return geometryAsString;
    }
```

Comment: incorrect, I wonder how you get 4 vote up.