# Windows Phone 7: How to parse Bezier Path string like in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bezier

I have a need to parse Bezier Path Strings, but apparently the `System.Windows.Media.Geometry`version in the .Net CF framework doesn't have the `Parse()` method that is available in it's normal counterpart. However, entering the following XAML does work, so there must be a way the system parses the Path Data String.

`<Path Stroke="Blue" Data="M 0 0 Q 10 10 20 0"/>`

Any clue on how I can initiate this parsing myself with a custom string outside XAML?

I ofcourse could also try to write my own parser using regex or so, but I would prefer not to handle this myself, since the framework clearly is capable of it.

**Update**

When using the suggested XAMLReader, I get a strange Exception when I set a StrokeThickness to the newly created `Path`:

```
path.StrokeThickness = strokeWidth; //ArgumentException ??? (strokeWidth = 6)
```

When I change codepath to render using my manual parser, everything works correctly.
Am I missing something here? Nothing changes except the parser.

Manually Generating Data:

```
        //"M {0} {1} Q {2} {3} {4} {5}"

        String regex_input = @"M (\d+) (\d+) Q (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regex_input);
        Match match = regex.Match(pathData);

        int startx = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        int starty = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);

        int controlx = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);
        int controly = int.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value);

        int endx = int.Parse(match.Groups[5].Value);
        int endy = int.Parse(match.Groups[6].Value);

        PathGeometry geo = new PathGeometry();
        PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
        figure.StartPoint = new Point(startx, starty);

        QuadraticBezierSegment quad = new QuadraticBezierSegment();
        quad.Point1 = new Point(controlx, controly);
        quad.Point2 = new Point(endx, endy);

        figure.Segments.Add(quad);

        geo.Figures.Add(figure);

        path.Data = geo;
```

Using XamlReader

```
        String formattedXAMLInput = String.Format("<Path xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Stroke='Black' Data='{0}'/>", pathData);
        Path xamlpath = (Path)XamlReader.Load(formattedXAMLInput);
        Geometry xamldata = xamlpath.Data;
        path.Data = xamldata;
```

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029680/wpf-c-sharp-path-how-to-get-from-a-string-with-path-data-to-geometry-in-code-n/16227344#16227344

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't currently expose an API for the path mini-language parser. It's internal to the XAML parser.

You can, however, create Path objects dynamically based on mini-language strings, using the XamlReader:

```
Path path = XamlReader.Load("<Path xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Stroke='Blue' Data='M 0 0 Q 10 10 20 0'/>") as Path;
```

Note that this won't actually expose the details of the geometry through the API to you, but you can display the resulting Path in your app.

Comment: Nice, that should work. However, now when I set strokethickness to the path I get a `ArgumentException` when using the `XamlReader` method. How's that possible? (See edited question)