# How to create such a Path in code?

Tags: wpf

How to create the following xaml in code:

```
  <Canvas>
         <Path Width="38" Height="9" 
Canvas.Left="-15" Canvas.Top="-1" 
Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FFF2F2F2" 
Data="F1 M 0.684,18.073 L12.790,5.968 L12.790,14.385 L54.794,14.385 L54.794,21.761 L12.790,21.761 L12.790,30.178 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): You don't create UI elements in procedural code in WPF. What are you trying to do?

Comment: For runtime VirtualKeyboard formation. My control allows to create any keyboard layout you want.

Comment: looks like something you would do with an `ItemsControl`, instead of using a horrible winforms-like code behind procedural approach.

Comment: If you don't know how - please, don't spam here.

Comment: spam? I'm trying to tell you what's the `correct` way to do what you're trying to do in WPF. WPF is NOT winforms. Please learn that.

Comment: I know what is WPF. Please, get out of the topic.

Comment: You dont understand all the requirements the project I'm talking about has.

Comment: And NO, you're just demonstrating you DON'T KNOW what WPF is, because you're insting in your dinosaur archaic horrible procedural crappy code behind winforms approaches.

Comment: if I don't understand the requirements, it's only because you have posted a poor question that doesn't really contain details about what you're trying to do. Go ahead and add more details about your actual problem instead of insisting in a crappy horribly bad solution.

Comment: `My control allows to create any keyboard layout you want` - you can perfectly do that with an `ItemsControl` and some `DataTemplate`s instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2029805/1683224

You can do this:

```
var path = new Path();
path.Data = Geometry.Parse("F1 M 0.684,18.073 L12.790,5.968 L12.790,14.385 L54.794,14.385 L54.794,21.761 L12.790,21.761 L12.790,30.178 Z");
```

Then change the other properties of `path` as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of Path and in the Data field, parse these `F1 M 0.684,18.073 L12.790,5.968 L12.790,14.385 L54.794,14.385 L54.794,21.761 L12.790,21.761 L12.790,30.178 Z` with the Geometry class.

for the position, use the SetValue method of framework element like `path.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, -15)`