# WPF; Convert between Path Markup Syntax and Geometry in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I'm looking for conversion between path markup and Geometry. I found a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029680/wpf-c-sharp-path-how-to-get-from-a-string-with-path-data-to-geometry-in-code-n) showing how to get the Geometry from path markup:

**Path Markup Syntax to Geometry**

```
string pathMarkup = "M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280";
Geometry myGeometry = Geometry.Parse(pathMarkup);
```

**Geometry to Path Markup Syntax**

Now what if I want to get the path markup from the existing geometry?

```
Geometry myGeometry = //some geometry
string pathMarkup = ??
```

Any idea how to convert a geometry to its equivalent path markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
Geometry myGeometry = //some geometry
string pathMarkup = myGeometry.ToString();
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for `CombinedGeometry` or `GeometryGroup` objects, both which are `Geometry` subclasses.  Anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [Hamlet Hakobyan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313039/340045), unfortunately the ToString() approach only works with Path Geometries.  So in order to apply this generically to all Geometry types:

```
Geometry myGeometry = PathGeometry.Parse("M 8, 0 L 2,25 16,25 Z");
string pathString = myGeometry.ToString(); // Works only for PathGeometry

GeometryGroup geomGroup = new GeometryGroup();
geomGroup.Children.Add(myGeometry);
geomGroup.Transform = myTransform;

string pathString = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(geomGroup).ToString();
```

Comment: Bingo!  You addressed the issue with the answer above.  This is perfect!